# Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am facing an error when running Spring MVC 5'

> HandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
>   WARN: [tomcat] [2019-09-16 14:00:32,390] [InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java{1}::postProcessBeforeDestruction{1}:163] Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'monitorService': java.lang.NullPointerException
>   WARN: [tomcat] [2019-09-16 14:00:34,167] [InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java{1}::postProcessBeforeDestruction{1}:163] Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'msBatchClientImpl': java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>   ERROR: [tomcat] [2019-09-16 14:00:42,148] [ContextLoader.java{1}::initWebApplicationContext{1}:316] Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4850)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5313)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:620)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

My dependencies versions are:

```
<java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.ws.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>2.1.10.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.data.mongodb.version>2.1.10.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>
        <mongo-java-driver.version>3.11.0</mongo-java-driver.version>
        <aspectj-version>1.9.4</aspectj-version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.28</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
        <commons-io-version>2.6</commons-io-version>
        <com.google.guava-version>21.0</com.google.guava-version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <jodatime.version>2.10.3</jodatime.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.2.2</postgresql.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>3.2.3</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.5</maven-clean-plugin.version>

        <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>1.0.2.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.10.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
```

Can u please help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code. How are you instantiating "mvcValidator"? Please focus on the message below, I think there is a problem in your code, it's failing while invoking the constructor of "mvcValidator" bean.

org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider; at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) at

Comment: I don't have any bean with the name "mvcValidator".
I am guessing it's related to my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very cool Intellij plugin called: maven helper.
I ran it's dependency analyzer on my Pom.xml and found a conflict of older hibernate validator version that was used on one of my submodules.